# Gridview if single item means it will place in to center

Tags: android

[image]

I need this layout i have done every thing but the First Gridview is having only one item i need to align it to center but it can,t it will like

[image]

I need this item 1 to center

here is my code

```
<GridView     
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridview_desc"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp" 
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:minWidth="180dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"

    >
</GridView>
```

any one please help.....

Comment: May i ask you why you want to use GridView for a single item?

Comment: its came from feed it may be single item or multiple item thus y

Answer (score 0):

Use ListView instead, and create item layout RelativeLayout and put a LinearLayout inside it as centered. And in code you need to calculate real positions of every item that you put and you can set position as a tag, and set onClickListener to handle with click event. You may want to remove listSelector as well.